# How to find probe sequence of keys?

Tags: hashtable, hash-function, probe, modulo

How would I solve this question? I'm sort of confused on how to start
The keys 34, 25, 79, 56, 6 are to be inserted into a hash table of length 11, where collisions will be resolved
by open addressing. The hash function is
h(k,i) = (k mod11 + i(1+k mod10))mod11
a. Calculate the probe sequence of each of the above keys.

Answer (score 4):

The Probe Sequence will be: 1,3,2,8,6.
To find that you should first put in the numbers into a table using the equation. Every time there is a collision (every time you try to put in a number into the table when there already is a number), you increment i (i starts at 0).

For example, the first number 34 is put in as h(34,0)=(34**mod**11+0(1+34**mod**10))**mod**11 which equals 1. Continue doing this for all the keys.

**Hash Table:**
0: 
1: 34
2: 79
3: 25
4: 
5: 
6: 6
7: 
8: 56
9: 
10:

So for the probe sequence, you would simply record in order of the keys which number they fall in under the hash table. Let me know if this helps or if I need to make any changes.

Comment: Isn't the hash table suppose to only 11 slots? You put 12.

Comment: My bad yeah, 0-10 is 11

Comment: shouldn't 56 be at position 4 ?